# UITableViewCell with custom control

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to create derived `UITableViewCell`.

The right side (cyan color, 200 in width but will be resized in future at runtime) contains my rating control.

On the left is a `UIView` (blue color) filling the remaining space. It contains a text label which takes all the space here. (In the future I hope to resize the the table cell in height, so it can contain whatever text is in the label.)

However, it utterly ignores my instructions. I have set rating control to have zero right margin. The `UIView` has zero left margin. The `UIView` right side = rating control left side.

And with the the fixed rating control width, it should work? But on the contrary. both things are pushed all to the left. (Like uiview with text label is maybe 20% width and rating control 20% in width - rest empty space)

[image]

Comment: Your UITableView or UITableViewCell might not be the width you expect. If you set the UITableView background color to red, and the UITableViewCell background color to yellow, and run your app, do you see unfilled red or yellow space?

Comment: If I press down on it changes color across the whole screen. Also detail/arrow to the right is at the far right. I also have cells of other types in the tableview which is coloured all way through. But I will try run time more tests and maybe post a screenshot.

Comment: please add a screenshot of all your constraints added in side the cell

Comment: The screenshot shows all constraints? unfourtnately, xcode does not allow to resize, so one can see them with all text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to read all your constraints but your "Score View" (lets call it A) and "Rating View" (lets call it B) must have **SEVEN** (I can only see 6 of them) constraints that should be pinned to their superview i.e. "Content View".

The constatins should be

A.leading = superview.leading

A.top = superview.top

A.bottom = superview.bottom

A.trailing = B.leading

B.top = superview.top

B.bottom = superview.bottom

B.trailing = superview.trailing

Comment: I think I in screenshot had replaced "B.bottom = superview.bottom" and "B.top = superview.trailing" with "B.CenterX = superview.CenterX" - but I am trying various things... Will report back if anything works (otherwise, I do not have it working)

Comment: I decided to redo everying wih botth a left and a right view (with rating control inside the right view) since everything behaved very odd. (Maybe some leftover invisible constrain in ide?) --- but it works now. In a sense your answer helped me in knowing I had not forgot something :)